# REGEX - Capture everything enclosed except specified sequence of characters

Tags: regex, ruby

I currently have this regex: `private(.*)`

That will capture `private` and any sequence of characters that come after it. This isn't exactly what I want though.

I want a regex that won't capture `private-name` and `private-id` but WILL capture everything else. How can I essentially "whitelist" the two criteria above?

Comment: Do you mean “`/private(.*)/` *matches* “private” followed by zéro or more characters, the latter being captured”? If you want “private” part of the capture it must be inside the capture group. Also, why the mad rush to select an answer? You don’t want to see others?

Comment: What should be matched and captured if the string were, `“privatexprivate-name123`”? The selected answer would match the entire string and capture all but “private” at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead for this:

```
private(?!(-name|-id))(.*)
```

This will only match `private` when it's not followed by `-name` or `-id`, and then capture the remaining string.

Comment: Actually, `private(?!-name|-id)(.*)` is enough, no need for another grouping inside a lookahead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wasn't aware of that, will remember for next time.